# Position background images for sprites

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I'm trying to use sprites for image rollovers but for some reson the code I'm using isnt changing the position of the background

Here's my code

HTML

```
<div id="top-social">
<a class="top-facebook" href="#">Facebook</a>
<a class="top-twitter" href="#">Twitter</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#top-social {
width:90px;
height:65px;
background-color:#FFF;
position:absolute;
z-index:9999;
margin-left:820px;
margin-top:-120px;
padding-top:15px;
padding-left:15px;
}


 #top-social a {
 display:block;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 height: 33px;
 width: 33px;
 background-image:url(images/social-icon-sprites.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 float:left;
 margin-right:8px;

 }

 #top-social .top-facebook a {background-position: 0px 0px;}
 #top-social .top-facebook a:hover {background-position: 0px -32px;}

 #top-social .top-twitter a {background-position: 32px 32px; }
 #top-social .top-twitter a:hover {background-position: 0px -32px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have errors in your css rules :

Change

```
 #top-social .top-facebook a {background-position: 0px 0px;}
 #top-social .top-facebook a:hover {background-position: 0px -32px;}
```

to

```
#top-social a.top-facebook {background-position: 0px 0px;}
#top-social a.top-facebook:hover {background-position: 0px -32px;}
```

(and the same for the 2 other following rules)

The rule you defined would mean that a `a` has to be in another element of class `top-facebook`.